# PHP MySQL - foreach loop with if to display subset list within key list

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to display records of venues, with a listing of rooms within each unique record. I have two tables, a venue_lookup table and a venue_lookup_room table. using the slow example I am struggling to ONLY populate each venue with the rooms that are contained within. I am able to echo the rooms into the venues, but I am struggling to restrict the rooms to ONLY appear with their unique parent venue. There is something simple that i am not seeing, I just know it.

```
//VENUE w VENUE ROOMS ARRAY TEST 2
$selCity = $_GET['theOption']; //Per Comment below modified $_POST to $_GET

$result5 = mysql_query("SELECT *
          FROM lookup_venue_room INNER JOIN lookup_venue
          ON lookup_venue_room.venue_name = lookup_venue.venue_name
          WHERE lookup_venue.venue_city = '$selCity' 
          AND lookup_venue.venue_name = lookup_venue_room.venue_name") or die('ERROR' .    mysql_error());

$roomNames = array();
$venueNames =array();

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result5)) {
  $roomNames[] = $row2['venue_room_name'];
  $venueNames[] = $row2['venue_name'];
}

$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lookup_venue WHERE lookup_venue.venue_city = '$selCity'")
   or die('ERROR:' . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result6))
{
  echo  '<h3>' . $row['venue_name'];
  echo  '<select name="rooms">';
  $venueNameOrig = $row['venue_name'];

  foreach ($roomNames as $roomName) {
    if ($row2['venue_name'] == $venueNameOrig )  {
      echo '<option value="' . $roomName . '" selected="selected">' . $roomName . '</option>';
    }
    else {
     echo '<option value="None">Non-venue-name-match</option>';
    }
  }
  echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: SO, I am not clear on your problem. Is you concern with the SQL you are trying to use to gather the data you are looking for or with code not behaving as expected? What is need for second query, as it would seemingly have all the same data as the first minus any records for which there is not a corresponding `lookup_venue_room` record.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query. This creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: @Mike_Brant My objective is to populate each venue record's select options with ONLY the rooms that exist in that venue. Right now every venue is displaying every room in their select options.

Comment: @tadman, Thanks I had planned to modify the $selCity variable to obscure it and maybe change to a $_Get request. I also planned to refactor this little bit of brutal code as mysqli. Still, I've been meaning to switch over to PDO and that link you posted is great, thanks!

Comment: @AndrewJO'Melia Good to hear. I'd recommend PDO over mysqli simply because it has named placeholders and those are lot easier to work with. If you have an associative array of parameters, you can bind against those directly.

Comment: Okay, I'm in the process of converting all my queries to mysqli, in the meantime, I'm still stumped on where my logic is going wrong in the above code. I am trying to contain the records for each room to only appear in the echo'd record their parent venue.